# Theoretical question on Hibernate Lazy Loading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I've learned that Hibernate allows the child elements to be queried only when it's necessary through the use of Lazy Loading.

So if we have:

```
@Entity
public class Payment {

 ...

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Debtor debtor;

}
```

I expect that when I fetch a Payment from the Database Hibernate set a placeholder in the debtor attribute **and fetches the Debtor only when it's strictly required**.

So if I use a getter method in order to get a Debtor from my Payment Object:

```
Debtor debtor = payment.getDebtor();
```

**I expect the thread blocks until Hibernate performs the SELECT query and return the Debtor object.**

So why the heck I always get an **HibernateLazyLoading exception** which obliges me to write a **custom fetch query** in the PaymentRepository, slowing down my initial query **AS I would have used an EAGER FetchType**?

So why does this `FetchType.LAZY` exists if it doesn't work as naturally expected?

Comment: Can you show and example code where this problem occurs. In my experience LazyLoading exceptions only happen when you try to access a lazily loaded field of the entity **outside** of a transaction. When the entity is no longer attached.

Comment: >So why does this FetchType.LAZY exists.  My opinion too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to specify @Andronicus answer because the answer is not accurate.

**LazyInitializationException**

It is not strictly related to `@Transactional`, transactions or open / closed connections.
Behavior is pretty simply (there is pseudo code below)

Without `LazyInitializationException`

```
Context context = Hibernate.openPersistentContext();

Payment payment = context.getById(1L, Payment.class);
Debtor debtor = payment.getDebtor();

Hibernate.closePersistentContext();
```

With `LazyInitializationException`

```
    Context context = Hibernate.openPersistentContext();

    Payment payment = context.getById(1L, Payment.class);

    Hibernate.closePersistentContext();

    Debtor debtor = payment.getDebtor();
```

**Questions**

> So why the heck I always get an HibernateLazyLoading exception which
>   obliges me to write a custom fetch query in the PaymentRepository,
>   slowing down my initial query AS I would have used an EAGER FetchType?

Because `Hibernate.closePersistentContext()` happened somewhere before.

> So why does this FetchType.LAZY exists if it doesn't work as naturally
>   expected?

Because we don't always need the entirely net of an entity graph.
We can use JPQL (HQL), criteria and projections to load parts of the entity. We need to explain to Hibernate how the entities are related, so we need to add the associations, like `@ManyToOne`.

There is a little problem here: mapping serves for two purposes

1. Explain to Hibernate how the entities are related
2. Save / Load entities

So the simplest way to disconnect loading from objects mapping is `FetchType.LAZY`.

**The simple rule**

Always use `FetchType.LAZY` everywhere and fetch necessary parts of the entity graph in the place where it is neeed.

Answer (score 3):

> So why the heck I always get an HibernateLazyLoading exception which obliges me to write a custom fetch query in the PaymentRepository, slowing down my initial query AS I would have used an EAGER FetchType?

It's because this sentence is not entirely true:

> I expect that when I fetch a Payment from the Database Hibernate set a placeholder in the debtor attribute and fetches the Debtor only when it's stricly required.

`Debtor` indeed will be fetched, if it's accessed, but only if it can be fetched. If you run it in a transaction (for example by annotation the method with `@Transactional`), the error will not occur, because the connection to the database is not returned to the pool / closed.

In your case the data is fetched, `Debtor` is wrapped in proxy and the connection is lost. If you try to access it, the `LazyInitializationException` is thrown.

P.S.: It's not recommended to use transactions to avoid `LazyInitializationException`, because of performance issues that might occut. If you fetch the parent and then iterate over multiple (say N) lazily fetched children, N + 1 queries to the database are shot.